# Working through AutoCAD 2021 Labs, not sure what lab #5 is asking me to do

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I'm working my way through these sample AutoCAD labs[(AutoCAD 2021 .NET training)](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/autocad) to get a feel for the system, and I'm really stuck on step #6 of lab #5. It asks me to "Check to see if the entry we are going to add to the dictionary is already there" using the "contains" property of a database dictionary(DBDictionary) in an if else statement. However, I can't seem to find any reference to what that entry actually *is* anywhere in the sample code or instructions. Step #7 Mentions an entity located *within* the aforementioned DBDictionary, but that seems like a particularly strange thing to search for, and even if it was what I was looking for I can't get a statement like that to work. I've tried. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`DBDictionary`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=OREFNET-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_DBDictionary) could be compared to a generic `Dictionary<string, DBObject>` and a `DBDictionary` entry to a `KeyValuePair<string, DBObject>` (where the `DBObject` is typically an [`Xrecord`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=OREFNET-Autodesk_AutoCAD_DatabaseServices_Xrecord)). The use of `DBDictionary` instances is a way to store data in an AutoCAD Database alternatively to `SymbolTable` (see [this topic](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-7313ECA1-4875-4946-82E3-C06A4074F807)).